# Degeneracy of complete bipartite graphs

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I think I understand the concept of the degeneracy of a graph, and I wanted to check if my reasoning for this is correct:

$\delta(K_{m,n})=\max\{m,n\}$

where $\delta$ denotes the degeneracy of the complete bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$. Is this correct? I was thinking that since degeneracy of a graph is the smallest value of $k$ for which it is $k$-degenerate i.e. every subgraph has a vertex of degree at most $k$, and in any subgraph of $K_{m,n}$ there would have to be a vertex adjacent to at most $\max\{m,n\}$ vertices in any subgraph of $K_{m,n}$.

Comment: There'd also be a vertex of induced degree at most $\min\{m,n\}$ in any subgraph. It's important to note that you are looking at the degree of the vertices *in the subgraph*, not their degrees in the parent graph. So for example, if your subgraph is an independent set, all the vertices have degree $0$ in that subgraph, even if they have higher degree when considered as vertices of the parent graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the definition of degeneracy, it is the **minimum** number $k$ such that the graph is $k$-degenerate. Certainly, $K_{m, n}$ is $max \{m, n\}$-degenerate.
But in fact we have $\delta(K_{m, n}) = min \{m, n\}$.
WLOG, let us assume that $m \geq n$ then we need to show that $G$ has degeneracy $n$.
Let's say the left part consists of $m$ nodes and the right part consists of $n$ nodes, then if the subgraph contains any left node, then each left node has degree at most $n$, and if the subgraph contains no left node, then it contains no edges at all.
And clearly, the minimum node degree in the original graph is $n$ so the degeneracy cannot be strictly less then $n$, completing the proof.